# how to get root node attribute value using linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML. How to read the root node attribite value and it's decendents using LINQ? I am trying to read "dId" and "dTime" from root node, "id" from Customer element and Order number.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <Customers dId="wqwx" dTime="10-9-09 11:23">
   <Customer id="1">
      <Orders>
        <Order number="22" status="ok">
      </Orders>
   </Customer>
 </Customers>
```

I tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
XDocument doc= XDocument.Load(@"C:\Customers.xml");
var q = from c in doc.Descendants("Customers")
        select new        
          {   
           dID = c.Attribute("dId"),
           dTime = c.Attribute("dTime");
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

first, fix your xml (`<Order .... />`)
then, your linq should look like this....

```
// .Elements(...) selects all elements of type "Customer"
    var q = from c in xDoc.Elements("Customers") 
    select new
    {
        dID = c.Attribute("dId"), 
        dTime = c.Attribute("dTime")
    };
```

you should [dl LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)... it lets you do Linq queries on the fly, even agains SQL databases. Then, once you get the results you want, copy and past your linq into your source code.

Comment: I just downloaded Linqpad: absolutely amazing!

Answer (score 1):

You have to end the order tag with:  `/>`

`xDoc.Descendants("Customers")` should work as well as `xDoc.Elements("Customers")`.

Chris, is there a specific advantage to using `.Elements`?

Comment: the .Elements lets you query on the element for child-elements with the specified element-type (in this case, "Customers")

Answer (score 0):

You can't use LINQ to access the root tag.
The code below does what you want (I included a well formed xml file as well):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ReadXmlSpike
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reading file...");
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Customers.xml");
            var customers =
                new
                    {
                        DID = (string) doc.Element("Customers").Attribute("did"),
                        DTime = (DateTime) doc.Element("Customers").Attribute("dTime"),
                        Customers = from customerxml in doc.Descendants("Customer")
                                    select
                                        new
                                            {
                                                ID = (string)customerxml.Attribute("id"),
                                                Orders = from orderxml in customerxml.Descendants("Order")
                                                         select
                                                             new
                                                                 {
                                                                     Number =(string) orderxml.Attribute("number")
                                                                 }
                                            }
                    };
            Console.WriteLine("Customersfile with id: {0} and time {1}",customers.DID,customers.DTime);
            foreach (var customer in customers.Customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Customer with id {0} has the following orders:",customer.ID);
                foreach (var order in customer.Orders)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Order with number {0}",order.Number);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

and the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Customers did="www" dTime="10-09-09 11:23">
  <Customer id="1">
    <Orders>
      <Order number="22" status="ok"/>
      <Order number="23" status="bad"/>
    </Orders>
  </Customer>
  <Customer id="2">
    <Orders>
      <Order number="24" status="ok"/>
      <Order number="25" status="bad"/>
    </Orders>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    XDocument d = XDocument.Parse(@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
        <Customers dId='wqwx' dTime='10-9-09 11:23'>
            <Customer id='1'>      
                <Orders>        
                    <Order number='22' status='ok'/>      
                </Orders>   
            </Customer> 
        </Customers>");
    var cu = d.Root.Elements().Where(n => n.Name == "Customer");


    var c = from cc in cu
            select new
            {
                dId = cc.Document.Root.Attribute("dId").Value,
                dTime = cc.Document.Root.Attribute("dTime").Value,
                ID = cc.Attribute("id").Value,
                number = cc.Element("Orders").Element("Order").Attribute("number").Value
            };

    foreach (var v in c)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("dId \t\t= {0}", v.dId);
        Console.WriteLine("dTime \t\t= {0}", v.dTime);
        Console.WriteLine("CustomerID \t= {0}", v.ID);
        Console.WriteLine("OrderCount \t= {0}", v.number);
    }
```

Console Output: 
 ================================
 dId             = wqwx
 dTime           = 10-9-09 11:23
 CustomerID      = 1
 OrderCount      = 22
 请按任意键继续. . .

Answer (score 0):

It does not work the way you wrote it: while printing the above code would complain about anonymous type.

However, with this simple modified version `d.Document.Root.Attribute("dId").Value;` you can assign it to a string.

Comment: The OP's code doesn't have a `d` variable created, nor is there an accepted answer for this question. In what reference is your answer to, and how is it different from the `cc.Document.Root.Attribute("dId").Value` answer provided by Laurel.Wu?